# @if statement doesn't works

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Good evening, I'm trying to make a log-in page that displays a redirection button when there are not registers in the users database. When there are one or more registers in the database, display all the users to select one of them. The problem is that the view doesn't change when the database has a register.

Here you have the blade template code:

```html
@if(empty($users))
                    <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
                        <div id="title">
                            <h1>Welcome</h1>
                            <p>We see there aren't users</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="loginForm">
                            <button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("/newUser") }}'">Create user</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @else
                    <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
                        <div id="title">
                            <h1>Select an user</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="loginForm"></div>
                    </div>
                @endif
```

Here you have the controller code:

```php
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('users.index')->with('users', $users);
    }
```

Here you have the web.php routing:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('landing');
});

Route::get('/newUser', function () {
    return view('createUser');
});

Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

Can anyone help me? I don't know to solve this...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't heard the populate term before (english is not my mother language), can you reformulate the question with other words, please?

Comment: Since your using (I guess) laravel Collection, you should use $users->isEmpty() instead of empty($users). If you want the users as array, use $users->toArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved, the problem was the routing with the blade's file name. I putted it in a login folder and changed the route in web.php

Anyways thanks to everybody for losing a little bit of your time trying to h

Answer (score 1):

`empty($users)` is not compatible with the result of `$users = User::all()`. `::all()` returns a `Collection`, which is an `Object`:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3357
  all: [],
}
```

Using `empty($users)` on this `Object` will return `false`. You can use a number of `Collection` methods, or the PHP method `count()` to determine this:

```
@if($users->count() == 0)
# OR
@if(!$users->count())
# OR
@if(count($users) == 0)
# OR
@if(!count($users))
# OR 
@if($users->isEmpty())
# Etc etc...
```

I'd recommend to use `->isEmpty()` for clarity, but I provided all of them to show different approaches.

There's a *ton* of useful methods available here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

Edit: If the same view is being rendered more than once, `$users` needs to be available, or checked via `isset()`:

```html
@if (!isset($users) || $users->isEmpty())
<div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>We see there aren't users</p>
  </div>
  <div id="loginForm">
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("/newUser") }}'">Create user</button>
  </div>
</div>
@else
<div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Select an user</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="loginForm"></div>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: If I do this, laravel throws an "Undefined variable: user" error :/

Comment: That's because your variable is `$users`, not `$user`. Check your spelling. Also, if you're using `view('index', ...)` in multiple places, make sure you're passing the same variable each time.

Comment: Just realized I wrote the first check as `$user`; apologies. Still a good practice is to never blindly copy and paste code; check that it is correct and won't break anything else, and use an IDE :)

Comment: Well, It stills throwing error, and I'm thinking about to make a LoginPageController to make a function in that controller and delete the @if in the blade

Comment: See my updated code; I suspect you've got multiple instances of `return view('users.index')`, and you're not passing the variable for each of those. You can handle this via `isset()`, or ensure you are passing `->with('users', $users)` on each one.